# Improve alignment when multiple duplicate suggestions are shown

Tags: feature-request, design, duplicate-questions

When a question you asked is proposed (but not closed) as a duplicate, there's a box showing duplicate suggestions. A while ago, I noticed it looks a bit odd when multiple duplicates are shown:

[image]

It would probably look better when

- the 'Yes'/'No' radio buttons are horizontally aligned
- the space between `0` and `answers)` is replaced with `&nbsp;`